# Nominalizations and the missing "the"

Tags: articles, nominalizations

*This guide equips you with a strategy to **ease adoption of** a new technology within your organization.*

Assume that I want to keep this noun (*adoption*). Is the article "the" missing here? Should it be *This guide equips you with a strategy to ease **the** adoption of a new technology within your organization*?

Comment: No, the article isn't "missing", since it was only ever *optional* in the first place. Personally I think having ***two*** articles (***the** adoption* and ***a** new technology*) sounds really clunky. I'd get rid of the second rather than the first, but there's no grammatical basis for saying either is "required".

Comment: Three. ***A** strategy to ...* And the first one is the important one; the others are generic indefinites.

Comment: I would actually say that the sentence makes more sense as "ease the adoption of new technology" (like FumbleFingers), because "adoption of new technology" allows for more interpretations of the  phrase "new technology." "A new technology" is singular, whereas "new technology" could be plural. Really, most "new technologies" are composites of other technologies, so this makes a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not missing. This particular "the" is optional and the sentence could be written as either of these:

> This guide equips you with a strategy to **ease adoption** of a new technology within your organization.
>
> This guide equips you with a strategy to **ease the adoption** of a new technology within your organization.

Answer (score 0):

*This guide equips you with a strategy to ease adoption of **a new technology** within your organization.* Indicates a technology that is not specifically named, nor invented.

This guide equips you with a strategy to ease the adoption of **the** new technology within your organization.  Indicates a known technology.

*This guide equips you with a strategy to ease the adoption of a new technology within your organization* The guide indicates that it informs on protocol on any existing or future technology implementation.